(UE 5.4.2) (Enhanced Input System) Touch Pressed trigger fires only once

As you can see on image I have three Control Bindings

Space Bar - works perfectly on desktop. I can press several times Space Bar and my binned function fires each time
Touch 1 - fires only once on mobile phone and when playing in Mobile mode. When I touch the screen on phone or with mouse in Mobile mode it works only first time
Left Mouse Button:

If I press the touchpad then it works perfectly
If I touch the touchpad then it works only first time



I think here are problems with touching system. Did I miss something?
How can I fix this problem?
